# White space above div

Tags: css

Please take a look at the following image..
[image]

As you can see.. I have added `:hover` property to the `div` enclosing each comment. but I get a small white space. When I use the chrome dev tools to highlight elements, the white space comes out of the area of all elements. it seems its a white space stuck between two divs. Please help me remove it. I added `margin-top` as a neg value but it gives a jerking effect on hover.

Comment: Try resetting your CSS. I put something like this at the start of every CSS file: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` This is just a basic example, since reset files can grow relatively big, but it might help...

Comment: Please show your CSS and relevant HTML code ...

Comment: A jsfiddle example that demonstrates the problem would be a big help.

Comment: as the others said need a bit more info, but it could be a whitespace issue. Try removing all space/line breaks between your elements and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I should have added a jsfiddle.

I had used a HR at the bottom of each comment and this HR had a margin after property. I removed hr and added a border-bottom for the div containing the comment. So that margin was removed. :)

Thanks a ton! I added padding to give space for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Without source to go on, I can only speculate about the HTML so bear with me.

Check for margins extending from the elements inside the `<div>`. If there's a `<p>` in there, the margins could be extending past the boundaries of the parent `<div>`.

If that's the case then this should do the trick:

```
div p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your layout is something like:

```css
<div>Line 1</div>
<div>Line 2</div>
<div>Line 3</div> ...
```

You'd simply need to reset their margins:

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You may need to apply this to `div:hover` as well.

Alternatively, you could look through your existing styling and (if it isn't user-agent styling causing this - which is unlikely for the `div` element), simply change your custom styling accordingly.